# What are the round-trips google mentions in the pagespeed insights tool?

Tags: apache, webserver, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

Google says it had to make 5 network round trips and that only 18% of the content above the fold could be viewed after the first 3 round trips.

How can I improve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `Pagespeed`’s docs this term is used multiple times in different contexts that is indeed a bit confusing

### Network roundtrips

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_delay_time):

> In telecommunications, the round-trip delay time (RTD) or round-trip
>   time (RTT) is the length of time it takes for a signal to be sent plus
>   the length of time it takes for an acknowledgement of that signal to be received.

So it’s more about the TCP protocol. From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/PrioritizeVisibleContent):

> If the amount of data required exceeds the initial congestion window
>   (typically 14.6kB compressed), it will require additional round trips
>   between your server and the user’s browser. For users on networks with
>   high latencies such as mobile networks this can cause significant
>   delays to page loading

2 recipes from the same page:

> To make pages load faster, limit the size of the data (HTML markup,
>   images, CSS, JavaScript) that is needed to render the above-the-fold
>   content of your page

and

> Structure your HTML to load the critical, above-the-fold content first

*Above-the-fold* content is the screen that can be seen without scrolling

More details on [mobile](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/mobile) analysis and **3** round trips

> Due to this TCP behavior, it is important to optimize your content to
>   minimize the number of roundtrips required to deliver the necessary
>   data to perform the first render of the page. Ideally, the ATF content
>   should fit under 98KB - this allows the browser to paint the page
>   after just three roundtrips to have plenty time budget for server
>   response latency and client rendering.

### Blocking roundtrips

From another docs [page](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/about):

> This section describes the round trips required to load the page’s
>   render-blocking resources, the total bytes used by the page, and how
>   it compares to the median number of round trips and bytes used in the
>   dataset. It can indicate if the page might be faster by modifying the
>   appearance and functionality of the page.

It’s not clear whether it means **networking round trips** that are calculated as above or simply additional calls required to load the blocking resources.

In any case you can fix it by eliminating render-blocking resources like synchronous javascript calls (more [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS))